# MongoDB Schema Redesign with existing data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, embedded-documents

I have around 200 000 Object names and 20 roles and  500 users. 
   Roles are categorized as admin,domain1,domain2,domain3,domain4..domain 20

Some roles (domain1,domain4 ) can only access to 5 object names and some other roles have access to 500-20 000 object names.
   Admin role have access to all the objects (2 million). So I've to map all the objects under admin role.
   So my data model would be like below.,

```
    {_id:1,
    Role_name: "admin"
    access_objects :{name1,name2 ..........name2000000}
   },
   {_id:2,
    Role_name: "domain1"
    access_objects :{name1,name2 ..........name5}
   },
   {_id:3,
    Role_name: "domain3"
    access_objects :{name1,name2 ..........name500}
   }
   ..
   {_id:5,
    Role_name: "domain5"
    access_objects :{name1,name2 ..........name5000}
   }
```

Here is the mongodb document 16mb limitation issue came. I'm not able to store 2 million object names in embedded document as shown above for admin.

So we did instead of mapping object names into role, the role is mapped to each operation . My current collection design like below.,

```
{_id:1,
    object_name: "object_name1"
    applicable_roles :{admin,domain1,domain2,domain3,domain4,domain5}
   },
   {_id:2,
    object_name: "object_name2"
    applicable_roles :{admin,domain1,domain5}
   },
   {_id:3,
    object_name: "object_name3"
    applicable_roles :{domain4}
   }
   ..
   {_id:2000000,
    object_name: "object_name2000000"
    applicable_roles :{domain4,domain1}
   }
```

In this model , We are facing slow query response.Some domains have access only few objects names but need lot of embedded loops to identify the objects.Already we have required indexes on the collection

Comment: 1. Please drop the "hello" and "regards" from your questions. This is not a cover letter for employment, but a question to your peers. Keep it relevant. 2. Have I not already commented to you about "scary numbers" in your question? I believe I have. 3. Take a good look at your structure proposal in your question and realize it is not valid JSON ( and therefore BSON ) and think again please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are a few suggestions that may help.

---

**First**, as you demonstrated, map the `applicable_roles` to the `object_name` since there will be *a much larger quantity* of object names than applicable roles.

```
// Do this:
{
    _id:1,
    object_name: "object_name1"
    applicable_roles :{admin,domain1,domain2,domain3,domain4,domain5}
}
// Instead of:
{
    _id:1,
    role: "admin"
    applicable_objects: {object1, ...., object200000}
}
```

---

**Second**, use an **array** as the element type for holding your `applicable_roles` (not an object with the role names as the property keys). As shown below, the `applicable_roles` are now in an **array**.

```
{
    _id:1,
    object_name: "object_name1"
    applicable_roles :[ admin,domain1,domain2,domain3,domain4,domain5 ]
}
```

*(By the way, the `applicable_roles` and `applicable_objects` are neither objects nor arrays in your post. Typo?)*

---

**Third**, take advantage of **[indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes-introduction/)**. By adding an index on the `applicable_roles` array then you will see improved performance.

```
db.yourcollection.createIndex({ applicable_roles : 1 })
```

*(If you have your `applicable_roles` as an object instead of an array then your `applicable_roles` object schema will be different for each row since, I'm assuming, the object keys are the role names. This format would prevent you from having an entirely useful index on an `applicable_roles` field since the object schema for that field would not be consistent across rows.)*

Comment: @whyceewhilt . Yes, Applicable_roles are arrays. Even I have the index on the array system is taking time to fetch the data. Apart from the data models mentioned above is there any other better  data models we can consider?